# ajax блокировка нативного javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.
Тема очень заезженная, но я ответа так и не смог найти.
Всем известно, что после подгрузки данных AJAX остальные скрипты выполняться не будут. Нужно, их инициализировать через success, ajaxComplete и т.п. 
Но я нигде не нашел решения относительно нативного javascript.
Все решения касаются jQuery!
Так получилось, что часть кода (фотогалерея) написана на нативном javascript. 
Весь код выкладывать думаю незачем. Листаются фотографии так:

```
var gallery = new Gallery(sources);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link, index) {
  link.onclick = function() {
    gallery.show(index);
  };
});
```

Как мне заставить данный код работать? 
Методы success, ajaxComplete пригодны только для jQuery.
Возможно, выше код попытаться привязать к jQuery, но как такое сделать - не знаю.

Утка Учится Уму - вы правы. Надо добавить код вызова.

```
var WORKS_METHOD ={

  handlerData:function(resJSON){

    var templateSource   = $("#works-template").html(),

      template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),

      worksHTML = template(resJSON);

    $('#works-container').html(worksHTML);        
  },
  loadWorksData : function(){        
    $.ajax({
      url:"https://path/to/worksdata.json",
      method:'get',
      success:this.handlerData
    })
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  WORKS_METHOD.loadWorksData();
});
```

Вызов AJAX подгружает превьюшки фотографий, по клику на которые вызывается данная галерея.
Вы предлагаете переписать вызов на xmlHTTPRequest?

Comment: в этом коде никакого ajax нету, $.ajax в чистом javascript - это объект XMLHTTPRequest (http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Да, ты прав. надо было привести код вызова.

Comment: так определитесь, нативный js или jquery. $.ajax - это jQuery. Значит он у вас уже есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте событийные функции [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - у вас есть ссылки, так что делайте аналогично примерам в документации:

```
$( ".myLinkClass a").on( "click", function() {
 var index = 0;
 // Вычисляем index для показа соответствующей галереи
 // ...
 // Показываем её
  gallery.show(index);
});
```

Индекс можно хранить в ссылке в data атрибуте, или же вычислять динамически.

Comment: Да, как оказалось - особой магии не требовалось.
Единственное -  `$( ".myLinkClass a").on( "click", function() {});` в обертке  `$(document).ready(function(){});` работать все равно отказывается.
Только через `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {]) ;`, внутрь которой поместил вызов объекта `var gallery = new Gallery(sources);`